# How can output sequence be equal to the sum of copies of the impulse response, scaled and time-shifted signals?

Tags: discrete-signals

I am sorry, this is a very basic question. But i am having hard time understanding is how it is possible.

I know impulse response is the output of the system when impulse sequence is given as input with initial conditions set to 0.

Scaling is to increase the amplitude of the signal, i.e. if i multiply the input by 2, output will also be multiplied by 2.

Time shifted signal is if I delay the input then the output is also delayed by the same factor.

Now can some one please illustrate this with an example how any sequence can be decomposed into sum of copies of the impulse response, scaled and time-shifted signals?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You seem to be considering a _linear time-invariant_ system although you have not said so explicitly. Are you wanting to know how you can say _any_ given sequence, e.g. one that was obtained on the basis of coin flips, can be expressed as a sum of scaled and time-shifted impulse responses? That is, given an arbitrary sequence, find the input to the system that will produce the given sequence as the output? If so, search for information about _deconvolution_

Comment: For more information on why the impulse response is important, see the answer to [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-is-meant-by-a-systems-impulse-response-and-frequency-response/544#544).

Answer (score 7):

One interpretation of your question could be as follows:

> Given that a system has the following two properties:
>
> 1. the *scaling* or *homogeneity* property that if the response to input $x(t)$ is output $y(t)$, then for any choice of $\alpha$, the system response
>      to scaled input $\alpha\cdot x(t)$ is scaled output $\alpha\cdot y(t)$,
> 2. the *time-invariance* property that for all choices of $\tau$,
>      the response to time-delayed 
>      input $x(t-\tau)$ is time-delayed output $y(t-\tau)$,
>
> then why does the system have the *additivity* or *superposition* property
>   that the response to input $x_1(t)+x_2(t)$ is 
>   $y_1(t) + y_2(t)$ where
>   the system response to $x_i(t)$ is $y_i(t)$, $i = 1,2~$ ???? $~~~~~~~~~~~$
>   More generally, why is the system response to input 
>   $\alpha\cdot x_1(t-\tau_1) +  \beta\cdot x_2(t-\tau_2)$ 
>   given by $\alpha\cdot y_1(t-\tau_1) +  \beta\cdot y_2(t-\tau_2)~$?

The answer is that a system with properties 1 and 2 does not
*necessarily* have the additivity or superposition property.
If the superposition property *also* holds, then the system
is called a **linear time-invariant system.** But this is an
additional assumption that you need to make (or prove).

Commonly, homogeneity and additivity are combined together
into the *linearity* property that says that the response
to input $\alpha\cdot x_1(t)+\beta\cdot x_2(t)$ (that is,
a linear 
combination of inputs $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$) is 
$\alpha\cdot y_1(t) + \beta\cdot y_2(t)$
(that is, the *same* linear combination of outputs $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$).

A couple of points that should be tucked away into the
back of one's mind:

- A system can be linear without being time-invariant (e.g.
  a modulator $x(t) \to x(t)\cos(\omega t)$, or
  time-invariant without being linear (e.g. a square-law
  circuit $x(t) \to [x(t)]^2$
- A additive system which produces output $y(t) + y(t) = 2y(t)$
  in response to input $x(t) + x(t) = 2x(t)$ and so *seems*
  to have the scaling property does not in fact have the
  scaling property. Persuade yourself that this is true by
  attempting to prove that the response to $0.5x(t)$ is
  $0.5y(t)$. In short, scaling and additivity are two
  different properties and a system that enjoys one of them
  does not necessarily enjoy the other.

---

---

A second interpretation of your question could be as follows:

> For a linear time-invariant system, the output is supposed
>   to be the sum of scaled and time-delayed versions of the
>   impulse response, but I don't see how this is so. For example,
>   the standard convolution result (for discrete-time systems)
>   says
>   $$y[n] = \sum_m x[m]h[n-m]$$
>   where $h[\cdot]$ is the impulse (or unit) response of the
>   system. But this seems to be completely backwards since the
>   impulse response is running backwards in time (as in $-m$
>   in the argument of $h$ in the above formula
>   compared to $x[m]$ in which time is running forwards.

This is indeed a legitimate concern, but actually the
convolution formula is very successful in *concealing*
the result that the output is the sum of scaled and time-delayed
versions of the impulse response. What's going on is as follows.

We break down the input signal $x$ into a *sum* of scaled
unit pulse signals. The system response to the unit pulse signal
$\cdots, ~0, ~0, ~1, ~0, ~0, \cdots$ is
the *impulse response* or *pulse response* 
$$h[0], ~h[1], \cdots, ~h[n], \cdots$$
and so by the scaling property *the single input value* $x[0]$,
or, if you prefer
$$x[0](\cdots, ~0, ~0, ~1, ~0,~ 0, \cdots)
=  \cdots ~0, ~0, ~x[0], ~0, ~0, \cdots$$
creates a response
$$x[0]h[0], ~~x[0]h[1], \cdots, ~~x[0]h[n], \cdots$$

Similarly, the single input value $x[1]$ or creates
$$x[1](\cdots, ~0, ~0, ~0, ~1,~ 0, \cdots)
=  \cdots ~0, ~0, ~0, ~x[1], ~0, \cdots$$
creates a response
$$0, x[1]h[0], ~~x[1]h[1], \cdots, ~~x[1]h[n-1], x[1]h[n] \cdots$$
Notice the delay in the response to $x[1]$.  We can continue further
in this vein, but it is best to switch to a more tabular form
and show the various outputs aligned properly in time. We have
$$\begin{array}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\text{time} \to & 0 &1 &2 & \cdots & n & n+1 & \cdots \\
\hline
x[0] & x[0]h[0] &x[0]h[1] &x[0]h[2] & \cdots &x[0]h[n] & x[0]h[n+1] & \cdots\\
\hline
x[1] & 0 & x[1]h[0] &x[1]h[1] & \cdots &x[1]h[n-1] & x[1]h[n] & \cdots\\
\hline
x[2] & 0 & 0 &x[2]h[0] & \cdots &x[2]h[n-2] & x[2]h[n-1] & \cdots\\
\hline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\
\hline
x[m] & 0 &0 & 0 & \cdots & x[m]h[n-m] & x[m]h[n-m+1] & \cdots \\
\hline 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  
\end{array}$$
*The rows in the above array are precisely the scaled and
delayed versions of the impulse response that add up to
the response $y$ to input signal $x$.*
But if you ask a more specific question such as

> What is the output at time $n$?

then you can get the answer by summing the $n$-th column to get
$$y[n] = x[0]h[n] + x[1]h[n-1] + x[2]h[n-2] + \cdots + x[m]h[n-m] + \cdots
= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x[m]h[n-m],$$
the beloved convolution formula that befuddles generations of students
because the impulse response seems to be running backwards in time.

Comment: This is a v old post; however would you be able to demonstrate the purported distinction between `additivity` and `scaling` ?

Comment: That bullet point is what I am asking about. It says *persuade yourself* - and -given that additivity and scaling are both characteristics of linear systems - I am not persuaded as of yet.

Comment: Is the dichotomy between additivity and scaling due to the discrete nature? i.e. additivity *does* imply scaling  for positive integers ?

Answer (score 4):

If we consider a discrete signal, say

x[n] = {1,5,3} , having three impulses at n = 0, 1 and 2 with amplitude 1, 5 and 3.

now, we can write

x[n] = 1*$\delta[n]$ + 5*$\delta[n-1]$ + 5*$\delta[n-2]$

or we generalize it,

x[n] = $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} x[k]\delta(n-k)$

For Linear time invariant system we know that,

for a given input, x[n] = $x[m]\delta[n-m]$, a system response as h[n], 
output $y_m[n]$ =  $x[m]h[n-m]$

Therefore, using commutative property,

y[n] = $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} y_k[n]$ = $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} x[k]h[n-k]$