# understanding discrete-time convolution in LTI systems

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, convolution, impulse-response

I'm trying to understand the discrete-time convolution for LTIs and its graphical representation. standard explanations (like: [this one](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/video-lectures/lecture-4-convolution/MITRES_6_007S11_lec04.pdf)) start with the idea of decomposing an input signal $x[t]$ into a sum of unit impulses. We have unit impulse function $\delta$:
$$
\delta[n]= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if}\ n = 0\\
    0,& \text{if}\ n\neq0
\end{cases}
$$

then $x[t]$ can be represented as:

$$x[t] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}x[k]\cdot\delta[t-k]$$

so the input signal at $t$, $x[t]$, can be represented this way because $\delta[t-k]$ is going to be 1 only if $t = k$, and 0 elsewhere. this makes great sense.

the confusion for me begins in **Transparency 4.2** of above [link](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/video-lectures/lecture-4-convolution/MITRES_6_007S11_lec04.pdf). the left hand side makes perfect sense, but what does the right represent? how does one unit impulse generate a sequence of responses? what does $x[0]h[n]$ represent here? How do you go from this to **Transparency 4.9** where $h$ is used instead of $\delta$?

put differently: can someone explain the intuition behind $h$ (the response of a an LTI system) being reflected and time shifted? in the above trick for representing simply the input signal $x[t]$, there's no time shifting really; $\delta[t-k]$ seems like just a mathematical trick for getting a $1$ in the right place and zero elsewhere; it's not intuitive for me to think of it as time shifted.

if we use the fact that in LTI, the response of a system to input $n$, $y[n]$, is just the superposition of the responses to unit impulses of input signal $x[n]$, why can't we write convolution this way instead?

$$y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}x[k]h[n]$$

Comment: Read the second half of [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/3495/235) and the whole of [this other answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6355/235).  Also, please form a study group with user9576 whose [question on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/922971/15941) is word-for-word the same as yours. He/she is confused by exactly the same things as you are!

Comment: @DilipSarwate: i followed your advice, could not understand how to get moderators to repost so simply reposted

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I read your answer several times. I follow the table, can see the calculation works (that you really get $y(n)$ this way) but it still doesn't answer the flipping. that you can flip the input instead of the response to signal impulse and get mathematically equivalent statement is clear. I still don't understand why the shifting/flipping of *either* $x$ or $h$ is needed.

Comment: I will answer only the last question in your post: "Why can't we write $y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[k]h[n]$ ?? Notice that $h[n]$ is a constant and not dependent on the index of summation $k$. Thus, your favorite way of finding the value of $y[n]$ gives $$y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[k]h[n] = h[n]\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[k] = c\cdot h[n]$$ where $c$ is the value (hopefully finite) of the sum of the $x[k]$ values. If this is what you understand by convolution: that for all $n$, $y[n]$ is simply a multiple of $h[n]$, then that is a problem that I cannot help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $h(n)$ is the system's response to the input $x(n)=\delta(n)$. Because of time-invariance, the response to $x(n)=\delta(n-k)$ is given by $h(n-k)$. If you write the input signal as

$$x(n)=\sum_kx(k)\delta(n-k)\tag{1}$$

then, due to linearity, you can write the output signal as the sum of the responses to each individual term $x(k)\delta(n-k)$ in (1), which is $x(k)h(n-k)$. So you get the convolution sum

$$y(n)=\sum_k x(k)h(n-k)\tag{2}$$

To compute (2) for a given value of $n$ you need to multiply $x(k)$ with $h(n-k)$ for all relevant values of $k$. Since you have $h(n\color{red}{-k})$ in (2) (i.e. with a minus sign before $k$) you need to flip the impulse response (shifted by the current value of $n$), multiply it with $x(k)$ and compute the sum.