# Difference between transfer function and frequency response?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-response, transfer-function

AFAIK both represent the ratio of the output response $Y(j\omega)$ to the input excitation $X(j\omega)$:

$$H(j\omega)=\frac{Y(j\omega)}{X(j\omega)}$$

Are there any difference?

Comment: The transfer function is more general because it can be the ratio of Laplace transforms of input and output. In the case of the frequency response, it is always assumed that it is a function of frequency only.

Comment: A nice [detailed answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-is-meant-by-a-systems-impulse-response-and-frequency-response) explaining what is meant by frequency response.